# Populate Datalist from the Database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, html

am new to javascript and php however i want to populate a datalist from mysql table but have some difficulties the relevant codes are presented below.I am able to fetch data from the database but not able to display them in the datalist element.

the HTML code

```html
<form class="form" action="insert.php" method="post" name="access_form">

<ul>

<li>
<h2>Please Fill The Form</h2>

</li>

<li>
     <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
      <input name="firstname" id="keyword" type="text" placeholder="type first name (required)" required />
      <datalist id="results">
 
</datalist>
</li>
```

this is the javascript code

```js
var MIN_LENGTH = 1;

$( document ).ready(function() {
 $("#keyword").keyup(function() {
  var keyword = $("#keyword").val();
  if (keyword.length >= MIN_LENGTH) {
   $.get( "auto-complete.php", { keyword: keyword } )
   .done(function( data ) {
    $('#results').html('');
    var results = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    $(results).each(function(key, value) {
     $("datalist").empty();
                                        $("datalist").html(data);
    })

       $('.item').click(function() {
        var text = $(this).html();
        $('#keyword').val(text);
       })

   });
  } else {
   $('#results').html('');
  }
 });

    $("#keyword").blur(function(){
      $("#results").fadeOut(500);
     })
        .focus(function() {  
         $("#results").show();
     });

});
```

the php code is below

```
  <?php
  require('constant.php');
   require('database.php');

  if (!isset($_GET['keyword'])) {
      die();
    }

  $keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
  $data = searchForKeyword($keyword);
  echo json_encode($data);
  ?>
```

please any suggestions

Comment: did you tried  `$("#datalist").html(data);` ? To select an alement with jQuery one should use `#`.

Comment: just tried but it did not work

Comment: I am sorry I thought you made `$("results")...`. In that case, you should use `#`.

Comment: Did you tried to setup `dataType` to json in your get function?

Comment: yes I used the jQuery to pass the data to json format

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `$.each` is going to empty the dataset for every result.

Try this instead.

```
$("datalist").empty();
$(results).each(function(key, value) {
   $("datalist").append($("<option>").innerHTML(data));
    })
```

You'll be creating a new `option` element and appending it to the `datalist` element.